# How do I start a function from within a *ngIf directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I am new to Angular.

How do I start a function from within a `*ngIf=` directive, when certain criterions are **NOT** met?

Note that in my code, below, the first *ngIf successfully displays a `{{tab1TrxMessage}}` message if a `tab1TrxMessage` is available.

```
<div (click)="clearForm(1)" *ngIf="tab1TrxId" class="sign-btn text-center fixedNotification" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <a class="btn btn-lg text-white" [ngClass]="trx1Btn">
       <span *ngIf="tab1TrxMessage">{{tab1TrxMessage}}</span>
       <span *ngIf="!tab1TrxMessage && tab1TrxStatus != 'Success'" "testing123()">Failed</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

However, in the second `*ngIf` directive, I if there isn't `tab1TrxMessage` **message** and the `tab1TrxStatus` **status** isnt of satus **Success**, I'd like this function `testing123()` to fire up!

Can anyone kindly help me understand how to achieve this as the current doesnt work.

Following is the `.ts` file content:

```
testing123(){
    console.log("Testing if this works!")
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the design intent here?

Answer (score 4):

Move it to method

```
messageFailed() {
  if(!this.tab1TrxMessage && this.tab1TrxStatus != 'Success') {
    this.testing123();
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

And call method in template condition

```
<span *ngIf="messageFailed()">Failed</span>
```

Comment: @Konrad Slotwinski I tried out our suggestion, however the `this.testin123()` function never gets called at all. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @theMayer you are right about the expression being called multiple times per second. However following @Konrad's suggested solution, the intention is to have an `alert()` function inside of the `testing123()` function informing of the failed status, which obviously rendered repeatedly. Would the change detection perhaps be an option in order to render the `alert()` once?

Comment: @SirBT - the purpose of change detection is to inform the DOM engine when to add/remove/update DOM elements. Using it beyond this purpose makes it very likely your application performance will suffer drastically.  Thus, you should be careful what you feed the change detector and never update state nor trigger any other behavior during change detection. `alert()` is triggering a behavior, so you should not do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not make calls to functions from within Angular templates.**  [why not?](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Angular evaluates the expressions contained within templates (including `ngIf`) each and every change detection cycle. At best, what you would be trying to do would depend upon the side-effect of a change detection cycle taking place. At worst, it would cause your change detection to slow down, possibly making your app less responsive or much more processor-intensive.

The `ngIf` directive is intended to display a section of HTML if the condition is true. Optionally, you can specify a `<ng-template>` to display if the condition is false (`ngIf-Else`).  To ensure your program is stable and usable in the future, evaluation of a condition *should **never** change the state of a program*.

**Where should this logic go?**

If you need to have something happen in response to an input variable, the appropriate place to do that would be on the setter.

So, in this example, you have two properties: `tab1TrxMessage` and `tab1TrxStatus`. The code below depends on whether you have private backing fields, so I'll leave that part to you, but here's what it would look like.

```
get tab1TrxMessage() { return this._tab1TrxMessage; } // assumes private backing field  
set tab1TrxMessage(v) {
  this._tab1TrxMessage = v;
  this.performCheck();
}


get tab1TrxStatus() { return this._tab1TrxStatus; } // assumes private backing field  
set tab1TrxStatus(v) {
  this._tab1TrxStatus= v;
  this.performCheck();
}

private performCheck(): void {
  if(!this.tab1TrxMessage && this.tab1TrxStatus != 'Success') {
    // note on the above - recommend defining 'Success' in an enum.
    this.testing123();
  }
}
```